# Have to log in to GameCenter every time you start in sandbox mode

Tags: ios, game-center

I am testing in the sandbox mode on the simulator and on a real device. Whenever I need to log in, it always prompts me for a password. This is unlike other games I have played where it simply logs you in and lets you play. I am thinking this might be related to the fact it's a test in the sandbox mode of GameCenter?

Can anyone confirm? Would hate to launch a product and have it be this way.

Comment: The Simulator seems to require a new sign-on with an Apple ID and  password whenever you switch the device you're simulating. If you stay with one device, the Apple ID sign-on should persist. Having said that, I must admit that there have been times when the Simulator 'forgot' the Apple ID and password, and Game Center asked for both again. You have registered the IDs in iTunes Connect, right? And the device too?

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this a lot recently using two sandbox logins on two real devices on a single network. One or both devices would prompt for login multiple times per day. I had a another problem where friend invites in the sandbox were never showing up, so after lengthy research on SO, I switched one device to a different network. Since then, the friend invites go through the sandbox immediately and neither device has asked for login credentials since that time.

Not sure why that would help, and I hope its not an issue for production servers. It might just be a coincidence and just started working regardless of anything I did.